# IF statement with logical && and || operators

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

I have the following code:

```
if (scanf("%d %d %d", &number1, &number2, &number3) == 3 &&
    ((number1 == rndNumber) || (number2 == rndNumber) || (number3 == rndNumber))) {
    printf("Champ!\n");

} else if ((number1 && number2 > rndNumber) || (number1 && number3 > rndNumber) ||
           (number2 && number3 > rndNumber)) {
    printf("else if!\n");
} else {
    printf("else\n");
}
```

If the rndNumber is for example: 10

and the input for the 3 numbers is: 1, 11, 1 or 1, 1, 11 or 11, 1, 1 or 1, 1, 1

The else statement will only be executed on the third and fourth input..I dont understand why

Comment: It looks like you're trying to see if two values are greater than a third value by doing `a && b > c`.  But that's just doing `a && (b > c)`, i.e. it's true if `a` is non-zero and `b > c`.  You need to do `a > c && b > c` to get the effect that you want.

Comment: If the return value from `scanf` is not `3` then in `else if` you checking values for `number1` etc that have not been entered. You must check the `3` before anything else. If it isn't `3` you must not check any value that was supposed to have been entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-statement of this if statement

```
} else if ((number1 && number2 > rndNumber) || (number1 && number3 > rndNumber) ||
           (number2 && number3 > rndNumber)) {
    printf("else if!\n");
}
```

will be executed when either number2 is greater than rndNumber or when number3 is greater than rndNumber provided that neither number1 or number2 is equal to zero.

For this numbers

```
1, 11, 1 or 1, 1, 11
```

this condition is valid.

For this numbers

```
11, 1, 1 or 1, 1, 1
```

the condition is not valid.

Pay into account that for example this sub-condition

```
(number1 && number2 > rndNumber)
```

is equivalent to

```
(number1 != 0 && number2 > rndNumber)
```